# Packages/libraries to build a Laravel 5 REST API

Tags: php, ios, rest, oauth-2.0, laravel-5

I'm going to build a back-end API REST using Laravel 5 for an iOS application (perhaps for Android in the future) so I found a couple of packages on github for the API authentication:

- https://github.com/chrisbjr/api-guard
- https://github.com/lucadegasperi/oauth2-server-laravel

And I want to know what's the different between them and what package could be the good choice for my API and of course If you have some advices or another packages to use, will be perfect.

Kind regards.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The oAuth2 server package follows [rfc6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749) and will help you have an Auth server like fb. (please see the link I provided for more information)

You may use a second app for it to separate your servers. (Auth server - resource server)

I never used api-guard but as it says in read me, It will provide a basic api key protection.

If you are planning to share your api with third party apps with user permission, I advice you to follow the oAuth2 path.

But if you are planning to use it in your app only, you definitely need api key only. Don't spend time for oAuth2 configurations.